# El chiste implicito en "Pareces fria, sujeta"

Tags: humor

Vi una composición de Les Luthiers en la obra [Hacen Muchas Gracias de Nada](http://youtu.be/pLTdZtOQERo) que se llama El Rey Enamorado (ve al segmento que comienza en el minuto 4:30).

En el mintuto 9:20 comienza una canción muy graciosa donde el serenatista canta una cosa y el músico la repite, conjugando las palabras apropiadamente con un fin humorístico. Al final de la canción, dice lo siguiente:

> --Pareces fría, sujeta.
>
> --Parece fría, su... su cara.

¿Cuál es la palabra implicita aquí? ¿A qué se refiere el "su..."? O sea, ¿cuál es el chiste aquí?

Comment: en que minuto dicen lo de la jeta?? jeta = cara

Comment: @EmilioGort: Minuto 11:45.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guitarist is trying to keep up with the other guy, he had to change anything he says, and sing it, but he has to say it in third person, since the idea is to get the woman to like the other guy.

The guitarist has a really hard time with this conversion, and almost screws it up by using the wrong word combo.

> Pareces fría, sujeta = you look cold woman
>
> Parece fría, su...jeta = her face looks cold

Since "jeta" means "face" or "mouth" seems like a common word, but it's not. In most countries is an offensive way to refer to the mouth, since this word is also used to refer to the mouth of a pig.

Comment: I suspected there was a reason why he hesitated saying it!  Now it all makes sense.

Comment: I think in _pareces fría, sujeta_, that _sujeta_ is not the noun _subject, individual_ (the woman in this case) but the past participle of _sujetar_, so she looks cold, restrained (as Diego points in his answer). Thus, it is even more funny that the guitarist changes that for "her face".

Comment: Still, the joke is more related to how close he was to use a rude word with the woman when trying to keep up with the verse by using "sujeta". The "face" meaning of "sujeta" is no longer used, it's more of an insulting word. I don't know about the "sujetar" part, it could be, that'd give a double sense to the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Es que como el guitarrista esta repetiendo todo lo que el dice agregando el `su` y jeta significa cara, el dice:

> sujeta
>
> su, (su cara==su jeta)

Answer (score 3):

First, `Jeta` is kind of slang for a funny or ugly face.

> Has visto la **jeta** de ese tío? Vaya **careto** más gracioso.

Note that **tener jeta** can also mean, "to have a nerve". The actual expression would be `ser un caradura` or `tener la cara dura`, and from that `cara` the word `jeta`can be used.

> Has visto la **jeta** de ese tío? Se acaba de colar en la fila!

Second, the first performer is addressing the queen as *de tú* while the second, the guitarist, is addressing the queen as *usted*, which leads to other misunderstandings (if I recall correctly, the first one is the king himself talking to his beloved, while the second is the poor guitarist that has to put into music the king's passionate words... So the king can address her as *de tú* while the other musician can't, and that is made explicit at the beginning of the performance).

The poem goes:

> Cuando (tú) **miras** con desdén, (tú) **pareces** fría, sujeta.

Means `you look cold, restrained`, and addresses the queen as *de tú*. The second guitarist starts with:

> Cuando (usted) **mira** con desdén, parece (usted) fría ...

and then he has to stop because the `sujeta` could be understood as `su jeta` (su *careto*), and he could be telling the queen that *her funny face looks cold*.

Comment: That's it! Restrained.